# What is the general solution of differential equation $y\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} - (\frac{dy}{dx})^2 = y^2 log(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the general solution of differential equation $y\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} - (\frac{dy}{dx})^2 = y^2 log(y)$.

The answer to this DE is $log(y) = c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$

I don't know the method to solve differential equation with degree more than 1. Please tell me how to solve these types of equations.

Comment: Is it $\log(x)$ or $\log(y)$ on the right side? Your equation transforms to $(\log(y))''=\log(x)$ which integrates differently.

Comment: You are right, the answer given must be wrong, I will change it.

Comment: Now with $u=\log(y)$ you get the simple linear DE $u''=u$ or $u''-u=0$ which has indeed the proposed solution.

Comment: Yo can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose $y\neq 0$, then the given DE is equivalent to
$$\dfrac{y\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}{y^2}=\log y$$
i.e. $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac1y\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)=\log y$$
By making the sustitution $u=\log y$ the last DE becomes
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}\right)=u\qquad \text{i.e.} \qquad u''-u=0$$
last equation is linear and homogeneous, its solution is given by $u=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$.

Comment: I am getting $log(y) = \frac{x^{2}log(x)}{2} - \frac{3x^2}{4}$ but this is not in the form of $c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  The equation can be written as
$$\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{y}\Bigr)=\log x\ .$$
There is in general no specific procedure for solving this kind of thing and you have to rely on "spotting" something like the above.

BTW I don't think the answer you have given is correct.  Probably the $\log x$ should be $\log y$ as suggested by LutzL.